# Ruby/Rails: Need to handle resizing of uploaded images with decent performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, image-processing

I'm building an app in Rails that allows users to upload images to their own galleries.  The images are shown in 3 sizes (at the moment: original, medium, thumb), and are resized (I'm using carrierwave & minimagick) as each file is uploaded, with the new sizes being stored on s3.

The first couple of prototypes I built were painfully slow when tested with more than 50 photos uploaded at a time, or when lots of people were uploading at the same time.

The two possible solutions I'm thinking of using are as follows:

1. Have the users upload the original size images to S3, then have a proxy image resizer to resize the other sized images. Initially resizing is done on the fly, then cached using Squid or Varnish.
2. Upload the users original images to S3, then have an image resizing app (built in sinatra or something small and quick) that can handle a queue of some sort (maybe using delayed_job), process the images & store on S3, and notify the main app when processed (so that the users are notified they're ready, and can be shown on the site).

I'm most concerned about the user experience here, so the quicker the better. I'm leaning towards #1 as it means people can access the gallery as soon as they've done the upload.

Can anyone shed any experience/light on which might be the best to go with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've gone with using Resque - it seems to be a bit more friendly than Delayed Job, and really makes a difference to the speed of uploading & resizing the images.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of an external app, I would use Delayed Job.

https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant that the external app would be running DJ to take the load off the main app server - I'll update the question.

Comment: @Les: In a Spanish social network called Tuenti, they use the first approach that you mention. As one user usually upload 3 o 4 images at once, the wait is not that important. How many images do you think your users will upload at once? You said you tested with 50 photos, but is it a common scenario?

Comment: 50 is probably going to be the estimated average - probably more, but until the beta is out there I'm not quite sure. I think I'm going to test both and see what the results are (unless anyone comes back with any more info on this Q). I'll post a link to my findings when I can.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using ImageMagick to scale your images.  ImageMagick is very, very slow (but feature-wise it's amazing).  I suspect you'll be able to scale your issues on the fly nicely if you use a faster library like gd.  I would consider trying http://gd2.rubyforge.org/.

Comment: I have written small post to resize an image using gd2 [resize image using gd2](http://railstech.com/2011/02/resize-image-using-gd2/)

Answer (score 1):

Which resize method are you using? In RMagick the standard 'resize' method is quite slow. There is a method called 'sample' which is the fastest resize method, but the final result will be a bit uglier. I don't know if the same applies to MiniMagick, but I guess it does, since it uses ImageMagick as well. :)

See this link for some comparisons (for RMagick): http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/resizing-charts.html

And I agree with Nerian. You should try delayed_job to queue up stuff. It's a very easy-to-use gem and I used it in some application with success. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider carrierwave-vips. It's about 6x faster than minimagick, on my computer anyway. This repo has some benchmarks:

https://github.com/stanislaw/carrierwave-vips-benchmarks